# How to solve equations in Calculator?

Tags: applications, calculator

When I place mouse over Calculator icon inside the 'Applications' menu it says "Solve simple equations". So I assume this can be done somehow. I tried these expressions.

```
solve(x=2x+3)
x=2x+3
```

It says "'solve' is invalid", "'x' is invalid" etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use NaSC, an application made by [Peter A](https://plus.google.com/116373568615209021512/posts) for elementary OS.

[image: NaSC]

More info at [NaSC webpage](http://parnold-x.github.io/nasc/)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to evaluate algebraic expressions with Calculator

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, but there is lot of other tools for that. for exemple, a simple website [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).